# Pandas rename columns from a JSON

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading a JSON with the following contents

```
{"aa": 10, "bb": 20}
```

```
df = pd.read_json("filename.json", orient='index')

print(df)
```

```
      0
aa   10
bb   20
```

How can I rename the columns of the data frame to something like "country, value"?

Answer (score 2):

here is one way about it

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
cols = ['Country','value']
df.columns=cols
df
```

```
    Country     value
0        aa     10
1        bb     20
```

OR

```
cols = [ 'value']
df.columns=cols
df.rename_axis(columns=['Country'], inplace=True)

df
```

```
Country     value
aa  10
bb  20
```